# how to set different values for id column of several tables

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update id column of several tables with `php uniqid()` values
after running this code - all rows inside each table has the same value
how to set different value for each row ?

```
$arr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'];  // table names
foreach($arr as $tb){
    $st = $db-> prepare("select * from " . $tb);
    $st -> execute();
    $arrb = $st->fetchAll();
    foreach($arrb as $elb){
        $id = uniqid();
        $sqb = "update " . $tb . " set id = :aid";
        $stb = $db->prepare($sqb);
        $stb->execute([":aid" => $id]);
    }
}
```

Comment: first make your table id column unique and maybe primary if there is no other primary key and secondly, why are you not making the column auto-increment and that way you don't need to manage the id column from code.

Comment: @dev_mustafa - cannot make id column unique if it is empty or has duplicated values. So I need firstly put some diff values. About auto increment - long story - but I want avoid it

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by Amitesh, your code is setting the same uniqid() value to all rows in each table multiple times. Furthermore, you are preparing the same sql statement for each row, missing one of the important benefits of using prepared statements.

```
$arr = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor'];  // table names
foreach($arr as $tb){
    /*
     * assign temporary UUID (requires CHAR(36)) to all rows if there
     * is no other way of uniquely identifying the rows
     */
    $db->query("UPDATE {$tb} SET id = UUID()");

    $st = $db->prepare('select id from ' . $tb);
    $st->execute();
    $arrb = $st->fetchAll();

    // prepare once per table
    $sqb = "update $tb set id = :aid where id = :old_id";
    $stb = $db->prepare($sqb);

    foreach($arrb as $elb){
        // execute once per row
        $stb->execute([':aid' => uniqid(), ':old_id' => $elb['id']]);
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no `old_id` column, that's the point. Of course I can create it if there is no other way

Comment: I'm expecting that sql engine can recognize and uniquely identify a record by itself. But never mind, I created a new unique column and deleted it after finished.

Comment: [InnoDB clustered index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-index-types.html#:~:text=If%20a%20table%20has%20no%20PRIMARY%20KEY%20or%20suitable%20UNIQUE%20index)